# rails form_for onsubmit with interpolated params not hitting js function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form_for html element. The form has an onsubmit attribute that calls a javascript function. The onsubmit works fine but when I add additional params the js function no longer gets hit.

The HTML generated by the form_for with the additional params is correct but for some reason the js function is not called. Any help is appreciated!

```
This works...

<%= form_for :item, html: { onsubmit: "saveItem(event)" } %>
  form content...
<% end %>

function saveItem(event) {
  js function content...
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This does not...

<%= form_for :item, html: { onsubmit: "saveItem(event, #{method}, #{url})" } %>
  form content...
<% end %>

function saveItem(event, method, url) {
  js function content...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your generated html and be sure your arguments to saveItem are quoted properly. Try `<%= form_for :item, html: { onsubmit: "saveItem(event, '#{j method}', '#{j url}')" } %>` - single quote the strings, and pass them through the `j` helper method - which ensures they are properly escaped for use by JS code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Scott. I tried adding the j to the params. The html of the form looks correct but it's still not hitting my js function. It instead uses the form_for default action and hits the corresponding controller.

I ended up just adding the `method` and `url` params to data tags in the div surrounding my form. Then in my js function I just grab the data values.